# Send a snap shot as an attachment in iMessage

Tags: objective-c, ios5, message, email-attachments, imessagefilter

We can send a photo as an attachment in mail using MFMessageComposer, I'd like to know if we could do the same thing with iMessage in iOS5.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Sending multimedia messages with `MFMessageComposeViewController` class is not supported.
2. `MFMessageComposeViewController` class right now sends only text messages. Support for `iMessage` is not added yet.

Comment: MFMessageComposeViewController supports iMessage in iOS 6. There is no visual indication that the message is going to sent as text or iMessage.